# How do I navigate to a new View from a navigationBarItem without using Sheets?

Tags: navigation, swiftui

I have an "add" button in the navigationBar of my app and I would like to display another view that fills the View instead of appearing modally like the view does by default when using Sheets.

Here is the code:

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: EditButton(), trailing: Button(action: {
         self.showingAddScreen.toggle()
     }) {
         Image(systemName: "plus")
     })
     .sheet(isPresented: $showingAddScreen) {
         NavigationView {
             AddTaskView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.moc)
         }
 }
```

NavigationLink pushes another view onto the stack. Is it possible to use **NavigationLink** with **navigationBarItems** or is there a better way to display the desired view full screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried something like this?

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: NavigationLink(destination: YourAnotherView(), label: {
                Text("Your Label or Icon")
            }), trailing: NavigationLink(destination: YourAnotherView(), label: {
                Text("Your label or Icon")
            }))
```

Answer (score 2):

There's no problem in using NavigationLink in bar button items.

To make the code cleaner instead of creating the code inline like this

```swift
.navigationBarItems(trailing: NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) { Image(systemName: "plus") })
```

I would create a computed property

```swift
var addButton: some View {
    NavigationLink(destination: SecondView()) { Image(systemName: "plus") })
}

// [...]
.navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
```

Make sure that you have a `NavigationView` on the first view only

If you want something more complex take a look into this post [How To Navigate Between Views In SwiftUI By Using An @ObservableObject](https://blckbirds.com/post/how-to-navigate-between-views-in-swiftui-by-using-an-bindableobject/)

It's what I'm using in my current project

Comment: I like this option as well because it provides a tidy way of building out the navigation options. Thank you.